# SvelteKit adapter-node deployment in subdirectory results in double slashes in url.pathname

Tags: cpanel, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I have a SvelteKit app using dynamic routes.

When I build with `adapter-node`, and then run `npm run preview`, the website works correctly locally.

*However*, once deployed to my web server when I visit `/bootcamp`, `params` returns as `{}` and `url.pathname` returns `//bootcamp` (notice additional leading slash).

Here is how I deployed:

1. Uploaded the `/build` folder and `package.json` to the `/courses` subfolder of my website https://www.valuespreadsheet.com, and installed the dependencies using `npm install`.
2. Used the **SPanel** NodeJS Manager to deploy a NodeJS app on port 3000.
3. Ran `node build` to run the app
4. Visited https://www.valuespreadsheet.com/courses/bootcamp, and was presented with a Svelte 500 error page. In my terminal I saw the console logs as mentioned earlier: `params: {}` and `url.pathname: //bootcamp`

Here is a partial snippet from my `+layout.svelte.ts` file:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
export async function load({ url, params }) {
    console.log("Request URL:", url.pathname);
    console.log("Layout params", params)
```

Here is my `svelte.config.js` file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        alias: {
            '$routes': './src/routes',
            '$routes/*': './src/routes/*',
        },
    },

    paths: {
        base: '/courses',
        relative: false,
    },
};

export default config;
```

Already tried changing the `base` and `relative` values in the config, which seemed to have no effect at all.

If it is of any help, my server is Apache based.

I already wasted multiple hours on this. What can possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `ORIGIN` environment variable?

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-origin-protocolheader-and-hostheader

I encountered a similar issue, when I had a trailing slash there. Removing the trailing slash from `.env` worked for me.